# How to keep web app on local and remote server connected?

Tags: svn, git, synchronization

In order to update a remote server's files, I have been copying files over which I have changed. Is there a better way to keep the files on the remote server and the files on the local server synchronized?
I watched a video where someone had an svn repository and just ssh'd into his server and checked out from the svn repository. I assume that he just committed his local server files onto the svn repository and checked from a repository source onto his remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Git, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614483/git-updating-website-when-pushing-to-remote-repository) may help you. For SVN, see these questions:

- [Deploying a Website from Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822469/deploying-a-website-from-subversion)
- [Using SVN With a Staging and Live Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739413/using-svn-with-a-staging-and-live-website)